# Tranpose react-csv list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, transpose

I am using the react-csv package to download a list of values stored in an array in a React app I am making like so:

```
<CSVLink data={[applicableCriteria]}>Download</CSVLink>
```

When I click *Download* and view the contents, I get a long row of all the list contents. Rather than being one long row, I would prefer one long column with the contents from my array. Is there a good way to transpose the 1-D array to accomplish this goal? Thank you.

`applicableCriteria` is an array of numbers, e.g., `["1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", ... ]`.

Comment: what does applicableCriteria look like

Comment: @cmgchess just revised the OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv) when you pass in an array of arrays
i.e `[["1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", ... ]]` each array in the main array is one row.
Therefore you will need to convert to `[["1.1.1"],["1.1.2"],["1.1.3"], ... ]` format.   Now there are multiple rows with 1 column.

```js
<CSVLink data={applicableCriteria.map(x => [x])}>Download</CSVLink>
```

[image: Edit react-csv (forked)]